# AJAX JQuery | accessing returned object data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, object

I am trying to access data returned in an Ajax call I have made. This is referencing the steam API and is successfully returning the data. I have console logged it to check. Whenever I try and access the data i get and undefined console message.

Below is a snippet of my returned JSON file

```
{
"playerstats": {
    "steamID": "Removed for SO",
    "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
    "stats": [
        {
            "name": "total_kills",
            "value": 7642
        },
        {
            "name": "total_deaths",
            "value": 7349
        },
        {
            "name": "total_time_played",
            "value": 427839
        },
        {
            "name": "total_planted_bombs",
            "value": 341
        },
```

Below is the code for my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.props.url,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success", typeof data);
        console.log(data.playerstats.stats.total_kills);
        console.log(data["playerstats"]["stats"]["total_kills"]);
    }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err, data) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
});
```

I am successfully entering the success function but it is displaying the following in the console

`success object` 
`Inline JSX script:21 undefined` 
`Inline JSX script:22 undefined`

the 2 undefined errors are appearing on the `console.log` line where I have tried accessing the Data the only thing I can think of is that I am accessing them wrong.

### Attempts

```
console.log(data.playerstats.stats.total_kills);
console.log(data["playerstats"]["stats"]["total_kills"]);
```

Comment: you have `corssDomain`, should be `crossDomain`.

Comment: your data.playerstats.stats is an array and not object. You cannot access the total_skills for it.. Please check

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal but the console log type of is telling me its an object `success object`

Comment: @RobScott same things happens with cross domain when its correct, updated now

Comment: Besides the data you are accessing is an invalid key.. The key is "name" and value is "total_skills"

Comment: Welcome to Javascript my friend.. typeOf(Array) = "Object"

Comment: data.playerstats.stats.forEach(function (stat) {
    alert(stat.value); //property for stats are name and value
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total_kills` is not a property of stats, nor even a property of every item in `stats`, but a *value* of the property `"name"`, you want the *value* of the property `"value"` of every item in the stats array:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.props.url,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success", typeof data);
        data.playerstats.stats.forEach(function (stat) {
            console.log(stat.value);
        });
    }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err, data) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
});
```

To get only the item which has `"total_kills"` as the *value* of its `"name"` *property*, you can use this :

```
var totalKillsObj = data.playerstats.stats.reduce(function(item) {
  return item.name === 'total_kills';
});

var totalKills = totalKillsObj.value;
```

Comment: When I try this I get `(193) undefined` in the console

Comment: This has worked, one more question. How do I get it to only access a specific item, say total_wins etc rather than returning everything

Comment: Well, you could use .filter() or .reduce() or underscore(-like) library to filter only the item which has `"total_kills"` as the value of its "name" property...

Comment: Note: `Array.prototype.reduce()` is only available in IE10+ http://caniuse.com/#search=reduce, so if you have to support IE <= 9, you can fall back to using underscore/lodash/rambda 's reduce function

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zum41jdg/1/)

```
var data = {
    "playerstats": {
        "steamID": "Removed for SO",
            "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
            "stats": [{
            "name": "total_kills",
                "value": 7642
        }, {
            "name": "total_deaths",
                "value": 7349
        }, {
            "name": "total_time_played",
                "value": 427839
        }, {
            "name": "total_planted_bombs",
                "value": 341
        }]
    }
}
alert(data.playerstats.steamID);
data.playerstats.stats.forEach(function (stat) {
    alert(stat.name + ":" + stat.value);//property for stats are name and value
});
```